# Получить корневой каталог Ubuntu в Java

Tags: java, ubuntu

Как в Java получить корневой каталог Ubuntu, то бишь `/`?

Comment: Что значит "в Java получить корневой каталог"?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Путь. new File("...")...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все очень просто,

```
Path root = Paths.get("/");
```

После получения объекта `path`, можно работать с корневой директорией,
например, узнать какие в ней находятся файлы и 
папки:

```
Files
     .list(root)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```